# Android Linearlayout weight weirdness

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm having a problem with this simple layout:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="10"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Title" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="45"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="First Name" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="45"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Last Name" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

As you can see this should split up the screen as 10-45-45, but the layout looks like this:

[image]

This seems to be a problem only with EditTexts.

Comment: When using weight, you should set the width of the views to 0dp. Also, the android:ems may be interfering with the weight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go -

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Title" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="45"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="First Name" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="45"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Last Name" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I set the `android:layout_width` to 0dp. When you use LinearLayout with horizontal orientation while using weight, you need to set the `android:layout_width` to 0dp and when the orientation is vertical, you need to set the `android:layout_height` to 0dp so weight can take effect. Hope it helps.

Comment: Well thanks, never thought that would solve this. :)

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
```

instead of

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```